# Rounding Hours to upper quarter with a flexibility

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to update a table with has an hour delta (called "Hours" in the table) to a rounded to nearest quarter hour on another column (called "RoundHours") and that, with a 3 minutes flexibility.

Here is my typescript function that does exactly what I want :

```
function RoundHourToUpperQuarter(hourNumber: number, flexibilityInMinutes: number) {
    if (hourNumber === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (hourNumber <= 0.25 + (flexibilityInMinutes/60)) {
            return 0.25;
        } else {
            return Math.ceil((hourNumber-(flexibilityInMinutes/60))*4)/4
        }
    }
}
```

My data is created with these lines :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `HR_CounterDay` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Source` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `Type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Hours` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `Project1Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Project2Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Calculed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_User` (`UserId`),
  KEY `FK_HRCount_HRProj1_idx` (`Project1Id`),
  KEY `FK_HRCount_HRProj2_idx` (`Project2Id`),
  KEY `IDX_Calc` (`Calculed`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_HRCountDay_Usr` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_HRCount_HRProj1` FOREIGN KEY (`Project1Id`) REFERENCES `HR_Project` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_HRCount_HRProj2` FOREIGN KEY (`Project2Id`) REFERENCES `HR_Project` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `HR_CounterDay` VALUES (18,13,'2019-03-21','P',1,0.71,NULL,NULL,2),(19,13,'2019-03-26','P',1,0.07,NULL,NULL,2),(20,13,'2019-03-27','P',1,0.00,NULL,NULL,2),(21,13,'2019-03-28','P',1,0.94,NULL,NULL,2),(22,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.99,2,2,2),(23,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.99,2,5,2),(24,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.99,2,NULL,2),(25,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.99,NULL,NULL,2),(26,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.00,2,6,2),(27,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.00,1,4,2),(28,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.00,3,4,2),(29,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.00,3,NULL,2),(30,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.00,3,6,2),(31,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.00,1,5,2),(32,13,'2019-04-04','P',1,0.00,1,NULL,2),(33,13,'2019-04-18','P',1,0.14,NULL,NULL,2),(34,13,'2019-04-18','P',1,0.14,1,4,2),(35,13,'2019-04-27','P',1,0.02,NULL,NULL,2),(36,13,'2019-04-27','P',1,0.06,NULL,NULL,2),(37,13,'2019-04-27','P',1,0.05,1,5,2),(38,13,'2019-04-29','P',1,0.18,2,6,2),(39,13,'2019-05-02','P',1,0.99,NULL,NULL,2),(40,13,'2019-05-09','P',1,0.99,1,4,2),(41,15,'2019-05-09','P',1,0.02,NULL,NULL,2),(42,13,'2019-05-13','P',1,0.17,2,6,2),(43,15,'2019-05-13','P',1,0.00,9,NULL,2),(47,13,'2019-05-15','M',1,0.99,2,6,2),(48,13,'2019-05-15','M',1,3.00,2,6,2),(49,13,'2019-05-15','M',1,2.50,1,5,2),(50,13,'2019-05-16','M',1,8.00,1,5,2),(58,15,'2019-05-17','L',1,8.00,10,13,2),(59,13,'2019-05-20','M',1,5.00,2,6,2),(60,13,'2019-05-17','M',1,5.00,1,5,2),(61,13,'2019-05-20','M',1,1.00,1,5,2),(62,13,'2019-05-20','M',1,8.00,1,5,2),(63,13,'2019-05-23','M',1,3.00,18,NULL,2),(64,13,'2019-05-23','M',1,5.00,1,5,2),(65,13,'2019-06-12','M',1,1.00,19,24,2),(66,13,'2019-06-12','M',1,2.00,1,4,2),(67,13,'2019-06-11','M',1,11.00,19,24,2),(68,13,'2019-06-13','M',1,0.25,19,21,2),(69,13,'2019-06-12','M',1,0.50,19,21,2),(70,13,'2019-06-11','M',1,1.00,19,21,2),(71,13,'2019-06-13','M',1,1.00,1,5,2),(72,15,'2019-06-13','M',1,1.50,1,5,2),(73,13,'2019-06-13','M',1,0.50,1,14,2),(74,17,'2019-06-13','M',1,8.00,25,26,2),(75,15,'2019-06-18','L',1,10.00,16,17,0),(76,15,'2019-06-18','L',1,10.00,16,17,0),(77,13,'2019-06-20','0',1,0.00,19,20,0),(78,13,'2019-06-20','M',1,0.25,19,20,2),(79,13,'2019-06-19','L',1,0.50,19,23,0),(80,13,'2019-06-20','L',1,0.50,19,23,0),(81,13,'2019-06-20','M',1,0.60,19,23,2),(82,13,'2019-06-20','M',1,0.10,19,23,2),(83,13,'2019-06-17','M',1,0.20,19,23,2),(84,13,'2019-06-17','M',1,0.40,19,23,2),(85,13,'2019-06-17','M',1,0.60,19,23,2),(86,13,'2019-06-18','M',1,0.60,19,23,2),(87,13,'2019-06-18','M',1,0.10,19,23,2),(88,13,'2019-06-18','M',1,0.20,19,23,2),(89,13,'2019-06-19','M',1,0.20,19,23,2),(90,13,'2019-06-27','M',1,3.00,1,4,2);
```

The objective is to add a column in which there are hours rounded to upper quarter as described above.

Examples :

```
Hours : 12/60 => RoundHours : 0.25
Hours : 30/60 => RoundHours : 0.5
Hours : 62/60 => RoundHours : 1
Hours : 64/60 => RoundHours : 1.25
```

Thanks in advance for your answers,
Zirion.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve].

Comment: I can't provide more code sample as my work is linked to a database I can't give you.

Comment: Sample data doesn't have to be real data. Just something to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Sample data added, I hope this is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add 12 minutes and then truncate to the nearest 15 minutes.

This is more easily accomplished in the domain of "seconds" rather than using date/time functions.  The idea is to:

1. Add 12 minutes to the date/time
2. Convert the date/time to seconds.
3. Truncate to the nearest 15 minutes (which is 15 * 60).
4. Convert back to date/time

Step (3) can be accomplished using arithmetic.  Here is an example:

```
select from_unixtime(15 * 60 * floor((unix_timestamp(now()) + 12 * 60) / (15 * 60)))
```

Just replace `now()` with the `datetime` value that you want.  Your data model appears to spread it among multiple columns.  I would suggest instead using a single `datetime` column.  But you can construct a `datetime` value from your time components, if you really want.